# Adding body css styling to meteor when using bootstrap

Tags: css, meteor

In my meteor app I have the following rules in my css:

```
body {
    background: #ddd url(../img/bg.png);
    padding-top: 120px;
}
```

This works fine locally, but when I deploy it, the css rules aren't picked up. When I inspect the element I see a reference to bootstrap (v2.3.0), which I added using meteorite, and the rule:

```
padding-top: 0;
```

Are the two conflicting? What are my options?

Following various explorations I found that repeating the tag works:

```
body {
    background: #ddd url(../img/bg.png);
    padding-top: 120px;
}

body {
    background: #ddd url(../img/bg.png);
    padding-top: 120px;
}
```

Nothing is picked up in the first tag, so:

```
body {
    padding-top: 120px;
}

body {
    background: #ddd url(../img/bg.png);
}
```

doesn't pad.

Comment: Conflicting: no. you forgot to mention the unit of padding (`padding:100px;`). if it still persists.. then look into the following
Options: 1. add !important like below or try looking for specificity in css if you can

`padding-top: 100px !important`

Comment: Use `100px`. Not sure why `100` would work locally though. Unless you're in quirks mode locally and in standards mode on the server.

Comment: @MrLister. It works locally on Firefox i guess. Does happen.

Comment: Sorry - that was a sloppy copy and paste. I've edited the css now so that is shows the full css I am using for body.

Answer (score 1):

I can only image that bootstrap css is being loaded after your defined css.
Try renaming your css file to main.style.css and you'll see your defined styles load after the bootstrap styles.

Files that are named main.* are loaded after everything else in Meteor.

Comment: I think you may be along the right lines, but this didn't fix it. If I simply repeat the body tag, however, it works, ignoring everything in the first body tag, using the second. No idea why.